# OpenOCD couldn't bind tcl to socket

Tags: openocd

I'm trying to launch OpenOCD but I'm getting this error:

`Error: couldn't bind tcl to socket: No error`

I'm sure the configuration is correct and I've tried with several different targets.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that this is caused by another process using port 6666 which is used by the tcl server.

To find out the process I've run this PowerShell:

```
$portProcessID = ( Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 6666 ).OwningProcess
( Get-WmiObject win32_process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessID -eq $portProcessID } ).ProcessName
```

After having the process name, I've run this PS to kill the process: `Stop-Process -id $portProcessID`.